# Calling a method from an array-list of objects

Tags: java, methods, static, arraylist, non-static

I'm just starting with Java and I'm having trouble with the following code. I was using something like this to call the non-static apply method from a static method, but I dont think its very efficient. I set an array list of the rules that need to be applied but I can't get it to work.

```
    ClassificationRule rules = new RuleFirstOccrnc();
    ClassificationRule rules1 = new RuleOccrncCount();
    rules.apply(aUserInput);
    rules1.apply(aUserInput);
```

I'm getting this error when trying to call the apply() method from ClassificationRule "The method apply(String) is undefined for the type ArrayList". Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
package tweetClassification;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PrioritRuls {

    //Set of rules to be applied
    final static ArrayList<ClassificationRule> rulesA
        = new ArrayList<ClassificationRule>();

    static{
        rulesA.add( new RuleFirstOccrnc() );
        rulesA.add( new RuleOccrncCount() );
    }

    // ******************************************* 
    public static void prioritize( final String aUserInput ){

        rulesA.apply(aUserInput); //ERROR
       // The method apply(String) is undefined
       // for the type ArrayList<ClassificationRule>
        }
} 
package tweetClassification;

public class ClassificationRule {

     // *******************************************
     public void apply (final String aUserInput) {  

        apply( aUserInput );
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, because you're calling the `apply` method on the array list object, not the contents of the array list.

Change it to something like

```
rulesA.get(0).apply()
```

Or, if you want to call it on every element, you need to iterate through the list.

```
for (ClassificationRule rule:rulesA){
  rule.apply(aUserInput);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response that makes perfect sense. Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**You are trying to invoke `apply()` on the `ArrayList` instead on the `ClassificationRule`** object. `ArrayList` does not have this method, so as expected - you get a compilation error.

You might want to **iterate** the `ArrayList` and `apply()` on each `ClassificationRule` object with a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html):

```
for (ClassificationRule rule : rulesA) rule.apply(aUserInput)
```

or to `apply()` on a **specific element**:

```
rulesA.get(someIndex).apply(aUserInput)
```

**One more thing:**

```
public void apply (final String aUserInput) {  
   apply( aUserInput );
}
```

will cause an **infinite recursive** calls to `apply()` [well, not exactly infinite, it will throw eventually an exception]. This is not the error you are currently having, since this is run-time error, while you are still stuck at compile-time errors.

Comment: You are most welcome @tom3322, and good luck! don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one of the answers later.

Comment: about apply() how do you suggest I fix that, i'm not getting any errors.. I'm trying to call the non-static apply() method of the rules using inheritance.